# MongoDB $or operator for multiple fields separately

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Looks like MongoDB supports $or operator only in the query root, and not per field query. So this doesn't work:

```
db.collection.find({
    foo: {
        $or: [ fooQuery1, fooQuery2 ]
    },
    bar: {
        $or: [ barQuery1, barQuery2 ]
    }
})
```

so we have to write it like:

```
db.collection.find({
    $or: [
        { foo: fooQuery1, bar: barQuery1 },
        { foo: fooQuery1, bar: barQuery2 },
        { foo: fooQuery2, bar: barQuery1 },
        { foo: fooQuery1, bar: barQuery2 },
    ]
})
```

Basically write all possible combinations for `foo` and  `bar`. But this is insane when we have to query by >2 fields with >2 OR-statements each.

It is quite easy to write a function which takes the fields and its OR statements from the first example and to generate all possible variations from the second example. But is there some MongoDB native approach, may be we are missing here something.

And may be you know the reason, why the first approach is not supported? So that we better understand mongodb internals.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways this query could be written, but it depends on the actual operations contained in each query.

If the queries are checking equality or a regular expression, you could  use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html#in) operator, like

```
{
   foo: { $in: [ "fooValue1", /^fooPrefix/ ]},
   bar: { $in: [ "barValue1", "barValue2" ]}
}
```

If the subqueries have other tests, like inequality or existence, you could combine each field's queries in a separate `$or`, with an `$and` operator to ensure a match from each one, like:

```
{$and: [
   {$or: [{foo: fooQuery1}, {foo: fooQuery2}]},
   {$or: [{bar: barQuery1}, {bar: barQuery2}]}
]}
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed with `$and...$or` combinations we can achieve the same result. Also `regex`s in `$in` operator is helpful, didn't know we can use it inside. I would also remove the outer `$or` operator, as only by using `$in` it solves the problem - from the question both, `foo` and `bar` should match.

Comment: Warning about regex - the query will only use an index if the regex is anchored to the beginning of the string.